# Can I use external javascript in mounted Vue area?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I have a template where I want to use Vue3 in. In the basic it looks like this:

```
<html>
 <body>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="photo-slider"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="/resources/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/photo-slider.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I mount Vue3 to the 'app' area, the photo-slider stops working. Normally I would use an alternative plugin but the template contains a lot of scripts that I want to use.

Is it possible to use external javascripts in the mounted Vue area?

Used scripts:
Vue 3,
Laravel 9.34,
Vite 3.1.5

Comment: This totally depends on "external script". You need to write it to fit the framework. If these aren't written by you, you can expect that they don't take this into account. If you want to do this to save time, it's not a good idea.

Comment: Also, if you can prefer using NPM packages rather than copy-pasta'd static code in a local directory. It will provide more flexibility regarding future updates.